# Errors running test cases with fluentui components

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, fluent-ui

I'm trying to run some simple tests in a reactjs project. I run into the following error when the component being tested has '@fluentui/react' or '@fluentui/react-northstar' imports -

```
 Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

      1 | import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    > 2 | import { registerIcons } from '@fluentui/react';
        | ^
      3 |

      at Object.__extends (node_modules/@fluentui/utilities/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:70:19)
      at node_modules/@fluentui/utilities/src/BaseComponent.ts:20:81
```

Does anybody know what causes this error in case of fluentui libraries and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to import a module which relies on React into your test is not going to work because when it runs the test suite knows nothing about React. It's just running on Node. Whatever `registerIcons` is calling is not in scope and so it fails.

You can use React testing libraries to help such as [Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/), which can be configured with Jest or Mocha, or [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/introduction/) which is a whole UI development tool.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue when upgrading from office-fabric to fluentui8. I solved it by updating my jest config moduleNameMapper as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaqyT.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35722480)